# scp through intermediate hosts

Tags: host, scp

I am trying to scp files to and from a remote server through an intermediate host. I can successfully do the following:

**Scp from remote server (lome.1470mad.mssm.edu) to local desktop through intermediate host (shell.mssm.edu)**:

```
scp -r -o 'Host lome.1470mad.mssm.edu' -o 'ProxyCommand ssh hernam13@shell.mssm.edu nc %h %p' matt@lome.1470mad.mssm.edu:/dir1/matt/ .
```

But I am having trouble copying files in the other direction **(from local host to lome.1470mad.mssm.edu through the intermediate host (shell.mssm.edu)**.

Can someone please clarify on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should just work the other way round (switching source and destination):

```
scp -r -o ProxyCommand="ssh  -W %h:%p hernam13@shell.mssm.edu" local.file matt@lome.1470mad.mssm.edu:/dir1/matt/
```

The `-o 'Host lome.1470mad.mssm.edu'` is no useful. The `ProxyCommand ssh hernam13@shell.mssm.edu nc %h %p` is better to use `-W` switch to `ssh`. If it does not work, what errors you get?